# JMeter: Aggregate report and Summary

Tags: java, jmeter

When using Aggregate (to use a access log file), then the summary reports one line for each line in the log file. 
Is there any configuration that the summary will only print one line for all the lines in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate will return one line for each LABEL.

Thus, if every request has a unique label, every request will have a line in the aggregate report.